# Element exchange between two vectors in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, dynamic-arrays

I have an interesting problem. I am simplifying it here.

I have one vector that contains: `a = { 13, 56, 76, 24}`
Another vector contains: `b = { 2, 74, 16, 29}`

I want to exchange the values, let's say `56` and `2`. So I want my arrays to be:

`a = {13, 2, 76, 24}`
`b = {56, 74, 16, 29}`

So the problem is: I add values to my vectors with `push_back` and I do not know where these values are stored in each vector. So I know that there is `2` somewhere in vector `b` and there is `56` somewhere in vector `a`. How can I perform this change?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Use [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) to find the elements in each vector
2. Check that the elements have been found
3. Swap the elements using [`std::iter_swap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iter_swap).

Example:

```
auto ita = std::find(a.begin(), a.end(), 56);
auto itb = std::find(b.begin(), b.end(), 2);
if (ita != a.end() && itb != b.end())
  std::iter_swap(ita, itb);
```

Comment: -1 negative valued verbosity, needless unfounded recommendation. `swap(*a,*b)` is (1) shorter and (2) more clear and (3) less to know about than `iter_swap(a,b)`. not to mention that it's the idiomatic default.

Comment: oh, and more portable

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I take the point of the questionable usefulness of `std::iter_swap` (in fact, I don't recall ever using it in real code, it just came to my mind for no apparent reason). But could you expand on the portability issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
std::vector<int>::iterator it56 = std::find( vec56.begin(), vec56.end(), 56);
std::vector<int>::iterator it2 = std::find( vec2.begin(), vec2.end(), 2);
if ( it56 != vec56.end() && it2 != vec2.end()) {
  *it56 = 2;
  *it2 = 56
  // or: std::iter_swap(it56, it2);
}
```